Spotless not working with Java text block
I am having a problem with spotless, when applied to a file with a text block.
I am using the following configuration for spotless in pom.xml. However, using eclipse java formatter has similar (but not exactly the same) problems.
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.43.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <java>
            <googleJavaFormat>
                <version>1.17.0</version>
            </googleJavaFormat>
            <indent>
                <tabs>true</tabs>
                <spacesPerTab>2</spacesPerTab>
            </indent>
            <indent>
                <spaces>true</spaces>
                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
            </indent>
        </java>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

This java file is not getting formatted correctly, i.e., the extra spaces stay, for spotless:apply
class SomeTest {

    @Test
    void test()     {
        assertThat("""
                
                """).isEqualTo("\n");
    }
}

This java file is getting formatted correctly, i.e., the extra spaces are removed, for spotless:apply
class SomeTest {

    @Test
    void test()     {
        assertThat("\n").isEqualTo("\n");
    }
}


I'd open an issue in github
